# Run network connection in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplication

I have this code who send data and receive even when the application is in background mode (minimized app):

**MyViewController.m**

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [self doUpdateEvenAppMinimized];
    }

    - (void) doUpdate{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            [self beginBackgroundUpdateTask];

            [self sendFilesToServer];//Inside this method have a sleep that call every 5 minutes

//The code used in sendFilesToServer is the same in this website https://dcraziee.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/how-to-upload-file-on-server-in-objective-c/

            //[self endBackgroundUpdateTask];//This method is forever...so I not need to call this line
        });

    }
    - (void)beginBackgroundUpdateTask{ 
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{   
    [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }];
    }

    - (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.backgroundUpdateTask];
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    }
```

The documentation says that the maximum time is 10 minutes, and to remove it I use the concept of **Implementing Long-Running Tasks**, For that I select my project > capabilities > Background Modes (Turn On) > External accessory communication (Checked).

With these steps, my application will be exempt from the 10 minutes?

Comment: Apple will almost certainly reject your app if it has the external accessory flag set but doesn't use an external accessory. Use Douglass Hill's suggestion.

Comment: @DuncanC If I use NSUrlSession with the external accessory flag set, My app will enter in app store?

Comment: Not unless your app actually connects to an external accessory. When you set one of the flags asking for special behavior, Apple makes you prove that your app really needs that flag.

Comment: If you use NSURLSession then you don't need the external accessory flag. NSURLSession has system support for downloading even when your app isn't running. It is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to circumvent the rules to run in the background sounds like the wrong approach. Consider using [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html) for long running networking operations that are not tied to the lifetime of your app.

Comment: Plus 1 for NSURLSession. That's what it's designed for. It will give you background downloading even when your app isn't running. Much better choice.

Comment: If I use the NSUrlSession inside my method sendFilesToServer, and continue not call the method endBackgroundUpdateTask, all things will be ok?

Comment: You do not need to use the background task API if you are using a properly configured `NSURLSession`. This is not a quick fix as the API is very different, but it is the right way. You should start by reading and understanding the documentation.